# How to apply which.min over a list

Tags: r

Assume we have the following list :

```
list_1=list(c(115222.321776569, 37864639.6868223, 880844.193064039, 
158574.408179366, 283899.102436544, 416531.537818319, 498992.661910475, 
312537.505136515), c(498992.661910475, 33741049.3285334, 492180.657601543, 
324174.022385466, 901091.893188845, 106068.170722435, 115222.321776569, 
710087.526882994))

# list_1

[[1]]
[1]   115222.3 37864639.7   880844.2   158574.4   283899.1   416531.5   498992.7   312537.5

[[2]]
[1]   498992.7 33741049.3   492180.7   324174.0   901091.9   106068.2   115222.3   710087.5
```

It's possible to use `which.min` over columns ( like a matrix ) to obtain minima indices :

```
mapply(function(a, b) {which.min(c(a, b))}, a = list_1[[1]], b = list_1[[2]])

# Output :

[1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

I don't know how to obtain this when the list has a `length` that is greater than `2`.

For example :

```
list_2=list(c(4,7,3),c(5,2,1),c(6,1,7))

# list_2
[[1]]
[1] 4 7 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 6 1 7

Output : 
> 1 3 2
```

Thank you in advance for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `max.col` + `cbind`

```
> max.col(-do.call(cbind, list_1))
[1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

and

```
> max.col(-do.call(cbind, list_2))
[1] 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
apply(do.call(cbind, list_1), 1, which.min)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: This is the same as transforming `list ` to a `matrix` ! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes, `do.call` will create a matrix and then you can `apply` your functions across the rows because the column number corresponds to which list the value is from. So you can have as many lists as you need.